# PhpStorm debugging - Path mappings misconfiguration

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I am running `PhpStorm 2019.3.2 Build #PS-193.6015.48, built on January 22, 2020` and `XAMPP 7.4.1.1`. My php/xdebug version is the following:

```
PHP 7.4.1 (cli) (built: Jan 16 2020 14:02:41) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.9.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2020, by Derick Rethans
```

My xdebug config in my `php.ini` looks like the following:

```
[xDebug]
zend_extension = /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.idekey = "PHPSTORM"
xdebug.remote_log = "/tmp/xdebug.log"
; host where debug client is running
xdebug.remote_host = "localhost"
; debugger port
xdebug.remote_port = 9030
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
```

Within PhpStorm I have the following setup:

[image]

[image]

I am using the Chrome extension to set the Debug-Cookie with the following key:

[image]

My app runs in `/home/marcus/Desktop/Code/todoApp`.

However, when running the debugger I only get:

```
Debug session was finished without being paused
                It may be caused by path mappings misconfiguration or not synchronized local and remote projects.
                To figure out the problem check path mappings configuration for 'localhost' server at PHP|Servers or enable Break at first line in PHP scripts option (from Run menu).
                Do not show again
```

Sometimes the debugger jumps into my php file (after 15 seconds) sometimes not.

Any suggestions why PhpStorm cannot capture the Xdebug session?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: 1) Is that site done using some popular framework? 2) Where breakpoints are set? If path mappings are correct, then that message means that you had some URL executed in this site but no breakpoints were hit. A typical example: missing `favicon.ico` image -- in frameworks all requests to non-existing files will be handled via `index.php` -- code executed but not where you had your breakpoints. Look into that -- check what URL got requested on web server log / browser's Network panel

Comment: Could also be a request to another domain .. but PhpStorm may wrongly detect it as "maybe this file belongs to this project just outside of it?.." I suggest collect and provide Xdebug log -- it will tell what file triggers it, then you can dig it further.

Comment: @LazyOne You are exactly right! In this example I am coding a wordpress plugin.